# How do I add different numbers in multiple lines in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have a file with 9 different phone numbers. There is a line for every call, and the duration. I want to add up the duration of the calls and match them to their own phone number.

Here is part of the file:

```
    7803214567;94
    7801234567;602
    7801234567;910
    7808765432;925
    7801234567;631
```

The first being the phone number and the second being duration in seconds. To be more clear, an example: `7801234567`, I want to add `602`, `910` and `631` and match it to its own phone number `7801234567`.

Comment: Can you read the file using python?

Comment: Any effort from your side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you just want to count the total number of minutes for each unique phone number.

You could use a [counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()

with open("path/to/file.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        k, v = line.split(";")
        c += Counter({k: int(v)})

>>> print(c)
Counter({'7801234567': 2143, '7808765432': 925, '7803214567': 94})
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

call_times = defaultdict(int)

with open('phone.txt') as fobj:
    for line in fobj:
        number, call_time = line.split(';')
        call_times[number.strip()] += int(call_time)

>>> call_times
defaultdict(int, {'7801234567': 2143, '7803214567': 94, '7808765432': 925})
```

`defaultdict` allows to specify a callable that creates a new value for a missing key. For example, this `defaultdict`:

```
>>> call_times = defaultdict(int)
>>> call_times
defaultdict(int, {})
```

returns `0` for a key it does not have:

```
>>> call_times['a']
0
```

because it uses `int()` for such keys:

```
>>> int()
0
```

Therefore, you can use `+=` to add up you numbers:

```
>>> defaultdict(int, {'a': 0})
>>> call_times['b'] += 1
>>> call_times
defaultdict(int, {'a': 0, 'b': 1})
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be `strip`ing even `call_time`?

Comment: @IronFist No need `int('  3\n\t')` returns `3`.

Comment: Ahah..ok..Then why did u have to `number.strip` ?

Comment: @IronFist If you want to look up the phone number you probably don't want a newline on the end of it.

Comment: @IronFist  The phone number stays a string. You could convert into an integer. But they often contain leading zeros and other characters such as `+`, `/` etc. Therefore, a strings seems more appropriate.

Comment: @MikeMüller...my bad...I thought you were converting `number` to `int` as well...I need glasses I guess ..:P

Comment: @PeterWood .. That is correct